# nothing happens when I click button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple webpage where the user enters in a number and the page tells the user whether the number they entered in is even or odd. I would like to display that in the textbox at the bottom of the screen.

However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I even tried to add an "alert" when the button is pressed, but even that doesn't happen. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta charset=utf-8 />  
<title>Compute the factors of a positive integer</title> 
<script type = "text/javascript">
function oddOrEven(){

 var userInput = document.getElementById('number');
 var number = number.value;
 var output = document.getElementById('display');
 alert(number);

 if(number % 2 == 0){
    output.value = number + " is even!"
 }else{
    output.value = number + " is odd!"
 }
 }
</script>     
</head>  
<body>
<form>
Enter a number to check whether it is odd or even: <input type = "text" id = "number"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="oddOrEven()">Click here to check!</button>
<input type = "text" id = "display">
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: have you got firebug or something like that to debug your code? If not you should install it. It will show you 2 errors

Comment: `var number = number.value;`?

Comment: Yes, isn't that going to take the value of what the user enters into the textbox? That textboxes "id" is named "number".

Comment: @NicholasRoberts then why did you add var userInput = document.getElementById('number');?

Comment: Just check console, and you will see problem(s).   var userInput = document.getElementById('number');var number = number.value;?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these three lines here:

```
 var userInput = document.getElementById('number');
 var number = number.value;
 alert(number);
```

You've retrieved a reference to the #number element and stored it in the userInput variable.  Then, you've created a variable called "number," but the value you assigned to it is a property of the variable you just created.

However, this object reference stored in the number variable doesn't have this property, which is causing a runtime error.  Try pressing F12 while in your browser with this script running and see what errors appear in the console.

Instead, try this out and see what reaction you get:

```
 var userInput = document.getElementById('number');
 var number = userInput.value;
 number = parseInt(number);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought you had to put the "ID" value before "value" which is why I originally had number.value, because "number" is the ID of that textbox. I see the error of my ways. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, how come that previous error stopped my alert from popping up? Now the alert pops up fine.

Comment: if there's a runtime error in the script it stops execution of the script completely.  You're script wasn't running at all.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple typos in your code, here's a modified version that I think ought to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta charset=utf-8 />  
<title>Compute the factors of a positive integer</title> 
<script type = "text/javascript">
function oddOrEven(){

 var userInput = document.getElementById('number');
 var number = userInput.value; // you originally had "number.value", but that doesn't make any sense.
 number = parseInt(number); // number is initialy a string, we need to convert it to an integer
 var output = document.getElementById('display');
 alert(number);

 if(number % 2 == 0){
    output.value = number + " is even!"
 }else{
    output.value = number + " is odd!"
 }
 }
</script>     
</head>  
<body>
<form>
Enter a number to check whether it is odd or even: <input type = "text" id = "number"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="oddOrEven()">Click here to check!</button>
<input type = "text" id = "display">
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake.

You wrote:

```
var number = number.value;
```

You should have written:

```
var number = userInput.value;
```